# Does this leaf belong to carissa macrocarpa?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I have a picture of a leaf and I am trying to find it's scientific name. The closer I got is *Carissa Macrocarpa* based on thorns alignment. If I am wrong, I need help in identifying correct species.[image]. Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: Adding some more images
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give more pictures (e.g. the thorns you mention, and of course any flowers, the overall growth habit - tree, shrub etc) and location?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I added few more images.

Comment: I think you are close with your ID, certainly down to the genus.  However, all the pictures I can find of *C. macrocarpa* have leaves which are slightly more peaked/acute, and have a tiny little spine-like structure at the end.  Also, it looks like the thorns are bifurcated, but your specimen has simple spines.  Since this plant is used in landscaping, there are various cultivars available which may combine characteristics of the cannonical species.  You might need to find a key to this genus to be sure.

Comment: Try to find a key for *Carissa* for your area if this is a "wild" plant, not landscape specimen.  I found several by googling.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that suggestion helped! It is highly likely that this specie is [Carissa carandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_carandas) which I found out grows in and around my locality.

Comment: Put it as an answer then with a little info about how you decided. It’s perfectly OK to answer your own question. Thanks for posting the question, I actually knew that plant indirectly from when I grew up in Southern California, where it was used as a landscape plant (and hurt a lot if a child tried to hide in a hedge of it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant seems to be [Carissa carandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_carandas). With the thorns placements besides leaves, I was sure that this plant belonged to genus *Carissa*. Taking advice from Bryan Hanson, I searched for the plants in the same genus in my locality(Hyderabad, India). The white flowers and their rosy stalk made it easier for me to search. I found out that this is a common plant in country side and is used in many dishes. Thanks Bryan for pointing me in the correct direction.